# Issue with singleton class constructor is private within this context

Tags: c++, singleton

I am trying to write a singleton class and I followed the standard template as below. But I get /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error:  is private within this context
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

```
status_publisher.hpp
```

```
    namespace test {
    class StatusPublisher {
     public:
       static std::shared_ptr<StatusPublisher> getStatusPublisher();

     private:
       StatusPublisher();
       static std::shared_ptr<StatusPublisher> instance_;  
    }
```

status_publisher.cpp

```
 namespace test {
  std::shared_ptr<StatusPublisher> StatusPublisher::getStatusPublisher() {
     if(instance_.get()==nullptr) {
         instance_ = std::make_shared<StatusPublisher>();
     }
     
     return instance_;
    }

    StatusPublisher::StatusPublisher() {

    // Some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As instance_ is initially a not a shared_ptr in your code, the .get() would not work there, as the instance_ is not a object like  `shared_ptr<StatusPublisher> { nullptr }`. I suggest you move instance_ declaration into StatusPublisher::getStatusPublisher, and return the instance_ there. As it is declared static, only one instance will be made.

Edit : I've seen another alternative answer that suggests to use raw pointer. However, as the shared_ptr has some pro-con to use the raw pointer, I suggest the shared_ptr version anyway:

status_publisher.hpp

```
namespace test {
   class StatusPublisher {
 public:
   static std::shared_ptr<StatusPublisher> getStatusPublisher();

 private:
   StatusPublisher();
   };
}
```

status_publisher.cpp

```
namespace test {
     std::shared_ptr<StatusPublisher> StatusPublisher::getStatusPublisher() {
         static std::shared_ptr<StatusPublisher> instance_ = std::shared_ptr<StatusPublisher>{new StatusPublisher()};
         return instance_;
     }

    StatusPublisher::StatusPublisher() {

    // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be good to explain to OP why they're getting error and also list those pros of `shared_ptr` use you advise. I don't see them because by making `instance_` static in scope of `::getStatusPublisher()` it is basically guaranteed to be initialized only once and then there's no point in using `shared_ptr` and OP can go with textbook singleton implementation.

Comment: @blami As the shared_ptr supports RAII, it provides safer access(with lesser chance to leak) to the memory. It is the benefit of the shared_ptr and unique_ptr. The raw pointer may give lesser overhead than the smart pointers, it have to be carefully managed manually by the programmer, which have more potential chance to introduce some bug to the program

Comment: I agree with @blami, there's no advantage to using `shared_ptr` in this case.  The fact that it's static means that it won't be destroyed until the program is shutting down anyway.

Comment: @MarkRansom Maybe we can just use static StatusPublisher instance_ and change the return type of the StatusPublisher::getStatusPublisher() to StatusPublisher&. Yes. It seems to be valid and more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you guys.. Actually switching to static StatusPublisher& (reference) solved the issue.

Comment: I have a follow up question.. When I use this strategy (static reference) I m not able to instantiate the object like 

auto status_pub = StatusPublisher::instance();

I m getting the error use of deleted function.. However I m able to directly call StatusPublisher::instance().someFnInStatusPublisher()

Comment: @Venk StatusPublisher::instance() is the instance of the StatusPublisher itself, therefore you need not to instantiate the object yourself like auto status_pub = StatusPublisher::instance(); Just call the singleton instance through StatusPublisher::instance() and use its functionality.